# Cannot dockerize app with docker compose with secrets says file not found but file exists

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize an API which uses firebase, the credentials file is proving to be difficult to dockerize, I'll be deploying using `docker-compose`, my files are:

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api:
    restart: always
    build: .
    secrets:
      - source: google_creds
        target: auth_file
    env_file: auth.env
    ports:
      - 1234:8990

secrets:
  google_creds:
    file: key.json
```

the key.json is the private key file

The Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM alpine

# Install the required packages
RUN apk add --update git go musl-dev
# Install the required dependencies
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux
RUN go get golang.org/x/crypto/sha3
RUN go get github.com/lib/pq
RUN go get firebase.google.com/go
# Setup the proper workdir
WORKDIR /root/go/src/secure-notes-api
# Copy indivisual files at the end to leverage caching
COPY ./LICENSE ./
COPY ./README.md ./
COPY ./*.go ./
COPY db db
RUN go build

#Executable command needs to be static
CMD ["/root/go/src/secure-notes-api/secure-notes-api"]
```

I've set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env from my `auth.env` to: `/run/secrets/auth_file`

The program panics with:

```
panic: google: error getting credentials using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable: open "/run/secrets/auth_file": no such file or directory
```

I've tried:

1. Mounting a volume to a path and setting the env var to that, results in the same
2. Copying the key to docker image (out of desperation), resulted in the same
3. Overriding start command to `cat` the secret file - this worked, i could see the entire file being outputted

Curiously enough, if I mount a volume, shell into it and execute the binary manually, it works perfectly well.

Comment: You need to run on docker swarm to be able to use secrets: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/